# Transition Animation Between Activities with AnimationSet

Tags: android, android-animation, android-activity, uiviewanimationtransition

The overridePendingTransition(int, int) method provides a way to animate between activities using the animation XML resources.

But what if We need to assign an AnimationSet (a bunch of animations that might even include a java animation too) as its arguments?

In other word how can we apply AnimationSets for transitions between activities?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to achieve that by using themes in my app.

Specifically by changing this style in a theme:

```
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Activity</item>
```

and overriding style Animation.Activity:

```
<style name="Animation.Activity">
        <item name="activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_open_enter</item>
        <item name="activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/activity_open_exit</item>
        <item name="activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_close_enter</item>
        <item name="activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/activity_close_exit</item>
        <item name="taskOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/task_open_enter</item>
        <item name="taskOpenExitAnimation">@anim/task_open_exit</item>
        <item name="taskCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/task_close_enter</item>
        <item name="taskCloseExitAnimation">@anim/task_close_exit</item>
        <item name="taskToFrontEnterAnimation">@anim/task_open_enter</item>
        <item name="taskToFrontExitAnimation">@anim/task_open_exit</item>
        <item name="taskToBackEnterAnimation">@anim/task_close_enter</item>
        <item name="taskToBackExitAnimation">@anim/task_close_exit</item>
        <item name="wallpaperOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_open_enter</item>
        <item name="wallpaperOpenExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_open_exit</item>
        <item name="wallpaperCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_close_enter</item>
        <item name="wallpaperCloseExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_close_exit</item>
        <item name="wallpaperIntraOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_open_enter</item>
        <item name="wallpaperIntraOpenExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_open_exit</item>
        <item name="wallpaperIntraCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_close_enter</item>
        <item name="wallpaperIntraCloseExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_close_exit</item>
    </style>
```

You can define your animation sets in XML and reference them in this style.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but suppose that I have a xml animation and a java animation (defined programmatically). now I need to combine and play these two at the same time in an event like "activityOpenEnterAnimation"